# How to groupby on several columns to know value on other column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with thousands rows like this:

```
city    zip_code   name
paris   1          John
paris   1          Eric
paris   2          David
LA      3          David
LA      4          David
LA      4          NaN
```

How can I do a groupby city and zip code and know the name for each city and zip_code grouped ?

Expected output: a dataframe with rows with unique city and unique zip_code and corresponding names in other column (one row per name)

```
city    zip_code   name
paris   1          John
                   Eric
paris   2          David
LA      3          David
LA      4          David
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? How looks expected ouput from sample data?

Comment: `df = df.drop_duplicates()` ?

Comment: Your output doesn't really match the description… what exactly do you want? Also are city and zip_code columns or indexes? Do you really want blanks in repeated values?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to know the existing combinations of city and zip_code?

```
[k for k,_ in df.groupby(['city', 'zip_code'])]
```

output: `[('LA', 3), ('LA', 4), ('paris', 1), ('paris', 2)]`

##### edit following your change in the question:

It looks like you want:

```
df.drop_duplicates().dropna()
```

output:

```
    city  zip_code   name
0  paris         1   John
1  paris         1   Eric
2  paris         2  David
3     LA         3  David
4     LA         4  David
```